# Contiguous multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, rust

I'd like to find a way to have a DST that is a multi-dimensional array, but with the underlying memory being contiguous. The contiguous requirement is mostly born from the fact that I'd like this array to have roughly the same shape as a multidimensional C VLA (but on the heap, since Rust doesn't support arbitrary stack allocations).

I'd *prefer* something that is not part of a third party library or doesn't require too big a definition - I'll be generating code including this, so I'd prefer the generated code not rely on a third party library or have a giant definition.

The main thing that would be nice would be to have index operations (which keep returning other multi-dimensional slices), preferably with `std::mem::size_of_val` returning the right size for the array, as well as indexes into the array.

Is this even possible?

Comment: _"I'd prefer something that is not part of a third party library or doesn't require too big a definition"_ You should not misunderstand Rust's standard library philosophy. It is meant to be ["a set of minimal and battle-tested shared abstractions for the broader Rust ecosystem"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.21.0/std/). As such, multi-dimensional arrays (other than just arrays in arrays) are not part of the standard. However, you should definitely look into [`ndarray`](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray).

Comment: Built-in DST references have two pointer-sized elements: a data pointer and a length (or vtable pointer in the case of a trait object). Would a reference to an N-dimensional array need N lengths?

Comment: @trentcl Probably yes. I'd imagine an extra field that is a slice of a vector of dimensions.

Comment: @E_net4 Hmmm. I look again at `ndarray`, but I really was hoping to find a self-contained solution. Thanks!